# Insert a WHERE clause into a SQL statement string

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I would like to have the ability to insert a `WHERE` statement into a SQL statement (a string) in python.  I know there is a `sqlparse` library, but I cant seem to determine how to insert a where token using that.  Can anybody help me figuring that out or have another solution into updating a string and inserting a WHERE statement.

For example if I have a string `"SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY col2 LIMIT 10"`, I would like to insert `"WHERE col5='something'"`, the final result will be `"SELECT * FROM foo WHERE col5='something' ORDER BY col2 LIMIT 10"`.  Of course there are a lot of edge cases here so was wondering if there is a library or a nice logic than can easily let me do this.

Comment: Assemble the SQL statement section by section *à la* Dynamic SQL.

Comment: In general the query may be complex, and it may have more than one place where WHERE clause can be inserted.

Comment: Do not insert into. Use original text as subquery, and add needed WHERE in outer query.

Comment: [`sqlparse`](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/) might help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
value='something'

SQL="SELECT * FROM foo WHERE col5='{}' ORDER BY col2 LIMIT 10".format(value)
```

Comment: Do not do this. This makes the code vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel whats the best way to avoid SQL injection.  But yea this answer does not help me at all since I may not know where the WHERE even start.

Comment: @user1179317 The best way to prevent SQL injection is using parameterized queries. Check the documentation of your driver for details (Python DB-API 2.0 specifies three different styles of parameters).